# Getting error "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" while pulling application list using azure-python-sdk

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm using a service principle with permissions Application.Read.All and Directory.Read.All of Application type to authenticate to Azure and using following code to pull list of Applications in the tenant.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient
from config import app

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = app["CLIENT"],
    secret = app["KEY"],
    tenant = app["TENANT_ID"],
    resource="https://graph.windows.net"
)

graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(credentials, app["TENANT"])

for app in graphrbac_client.applications.list():
    print("\nApp:")
    print(app)
print("******\n")
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you also pressed the grant consent button in the API permissions tab of your app registration?

Comment: Any update this issue? Is my reply helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Application.Read.All and Directory.Read.All these 2 permissions requires Global Administrator consent for your directory. I would suggest to ask your Global Administrator to provide consent to your service principal.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I suppose you added the *application permission* `Application.Read.All` and `Directory.Read.All` of `Microsoft Graph`, because what you need is `Azure Active Directory Graph`, which does not have the `Application.Read.All` permission.

[image]

In your code, it uses the `resource="https://graph.windows.net"`, which means your code calls the `Azure Active Directory Graph`, not `Microsoft Graph`, to solve the issue, just add the *application permission* `Directory.Read.All` of `Azure Active Directory Graph` like below.

[image]

[image]

**Note** : After adding the permission, don't forget to click the `Grant admin consent for xxx` button, otherwise your service principal will not get the permission.

[image]

---

There may be some delay, after half an hour, test the code, it works fine.

[image]